# Can't click on anything after a little bit during install

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

I've been try to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Inspiron 15 7000 gaming. I can boot to the USB, and open a live session or get to the install page directly. But after about a minute, the system locks up and I can't click on anything, just move the mouse.

I did have a dual boot installed previously. I got a new NVMe SSD recently, and completely redid my computer. I do have space set aside for Ubuntu though.

I am able to install 18.10, but that freezes after signing in when completely installed. It gets to a purple screen with the cursor in the bottom right corner, but stays there.

I did notice some errors when booting. I don't quite know what they mean. I'm attaching a picture of them. Please excuse the quality, it went by so fast that I had to record it, take a screenshot, and crop it.

[image: screen photo]